# Fuzzy matching using sphinx in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using Sphinx for searching in rails 2.3.4. And thinking-sphinx gem(1.4.4) AND thinking-sphinx-raspell(1.0.0)

In configuration i added the things below.

morphology = metaphone, stem_en, libstemmer_sv, soundex

min_stemming_len = 4

charset_type = utf-8

min_infix_len = 3

enable_star = 1

Now i give a string "sny" for search

It give the results like "syn" and not like "sony"

If i use double meta phone in postgresql means it give the result, that contains "sony"

how to configure the sphinx for fuzzy matching to get the result as above ?